# Composer Update generating "File Not Found" error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, command-line-interface

I am developing a Laravel app and am getting ready to stage the code.  However when I ran a final `composer update` to verify everything, I get the following error:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information

  [UnexpectedValueException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(packages): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

I have tried clearing the composer cache with `composer clearcache`.  I have tried dumping autoloads with `composer dumpautoloads`.

I am sure that it is something that I have done, but it seemed to just happen out of no where.

Below is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "test/tickets",
    "description": "Ticketing System",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "~2.0",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0",
        "contao-community-alliance/composer-client": "~0.14"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://legacy-packages-via.contao-community-alliance.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "packages"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "../assets/components"
    }
}
```

Any direction that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: run `composer install`, you may need to clear out your vender folder

Comment: When in doubt, rm -rf vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys.  I ended up creating a new,clean composer.json using `composer init` and only requiring the necessary packages (basically the same as above without the composer-client).  I then removed the entire vendor directory with `rm -rf vendor` and ran `composer install`.  Everything was then downloaded and installed successfully.  `composer update` works now.  Thank you for the ideas.

Comment: @JoshRipley you can post this as an answer and mark it as solved, so other users can see that this question has a solution.

Comment: @Peh Thanks you. Will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new,clean composer.json using `composer init` and only requiring the necessary packages (basically the same as above without the composer-client). I then removed the entire vendor directory with `rm -rf vendor` and ran `composer install`. Everything was then downloaded and installed successfully. `composer update` works now.